# Geopandas overlay intersection

Tags: python, intersection, geopandas

I'm trying to find intersections of two sets of polygons, with one set of them being some census tracts selected from the CENSUS data product(poly1), the other set of polygons defined by myself(poly2). I'm interested to see which census tracts fall into each of my polygons (intersection) and from there calculate the area of intersected census tracts and so on and so forth.

I used the following code:

```
import geopandas as gp
gp.overlay(censustracts, mypolygons, how = 'intersection')
```

This works fine for cases where there are not too many census tracts involved. I handpicked some cases (5000~40,000 census tracts) and did the intersection computation in ArcMap and cross-checked the results. It seems geopandas.overlay give less accurate results: sometimes the given 'intersected' census tracts are NOT supposed to be counted as intersection; sometimes the should-be-intersected census tracts are missing.

Moreover, if I only pick one polygon from my self-defined polygons (poly2) and pick the correct census tracts it should intersect with, geopandas.overlay works correctly.

I don't know why this is happening. It seems there is only discussion about the speed of geopandas overlay (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/400), but I haven't found anything about the accuracy. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked if both GeoDataFrames have the same `crs`? That's something that I often forget to check and can be the source of a lot of trouble.